# Attach IAM Policy to SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying deliver a message from an unencrypted SNS topic to an encrypted SQS queue following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-topic-sqs-queue-sse-cmk-policy/). I was able to complete the "Configure KMS permissions for AWS services" step, but I am having trouble with the "Configure KMS permissions for producers
" step. I have created the IAM role, however attaching this role to my SNS topic is where I am specifically confused. Here are some questions I have which my own research was unable to answer:

- Can an IAM role be attached to a specific item (SNS topic, SQS queue, etc...)? If not, what other way is there to grant permissions to a specific item?
- When the instructions mention "producer", is this referring to the SNS topic or the AWS account which owns the SNS topic?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

Here is my current AWS KMS key policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${aws_account_id}:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow SNS to use KMS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I add the following statements to my KMS key policy in the `Statement` list, I get the error "MalformedPolicyDocumentException - Policy contains a statement with no principal":

```js
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": "${kms_customer_managed_key_arn}"
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage"
    ],
    "Resource": "${sqs_queue_arn}"
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what is the producer?

Answer (score 0):

> If not, what other way is there to grant permissions to a specific item?

The permissons from the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html#compatibility-with-aws-services) are attached to your [KMS CMK key policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html).

> When the instructions mention "producer", is this referring to the SNS topic or the AWS account which owns the SNS topic?

The producer is anyone or anything that sends messages. It can be a lambda function, an ec2 instance or IAM user/role. In that case you give the producer permissions to `sendMessage` and use the KMS key. For lambda it would be in lambda execution role, for instance it would be in an  instance role.

Comment: When attaching the permissions in the "Configure KMS permissions for producers" section to the KMS CMK key policy, I get this error: "MalformedPolicyDocumentException - Policy contains a statement with no principal." If I add the SNS topic's ARN as the principal, I get this error: "MalformedPolicyDocumentException - Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals." That section states to "add the following statement to the IAM policy of the producer", in this case the SNS topic, but I am still unable to attach these permissions to my SNS topic. Any advice?

Comment: @dmoini Your are  not showing any of your policies. I would suggest making new question with the relevant policies that you are trying to use.

Comment: I just updated the question with my current policies. Would this information help?

Comment: @dmoini Sorry, buts not a good practice to totally change your existing question into new question. You ask about explanations regarding producer and IAM role. Now you change your question to a totally new issue.

Comment: New question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912956/messages-from-unencrypted-sns-topic-not-reaching-encrypted-sqs-queue). If you have the time can you take a look at it?