# Messages From Unencrypted SNS Topic Not Reaching Encrypted SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

I have an unencrypted SNS topic with an encrypted SQS queue subscribed to it. Whenever I publish messages from the SNS topic, the SQS queue does not receive the message (the SQS queue receives messages successfully from the SNS topic when encryption is disabled). So far I have been following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html). Here is what I have completed so far:

1. Create KMS customer managed key (CMK) with the following key policy ("Configure KMS permissions for AWS services" section in linked guide):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${aws_account_id}:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow SNS to use KMS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently I am stuck on the "Configure KMS permissions for producers" section. When I add the following statement in the `Statement` list of my KMS CMK's key policy, I get the error `MalformedPolicyDocumentException - Policy contains a statement with no principal`.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": "${kms_customer_managed_key_arn}"
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage"
    ],
    "Resource": "${sqs_queue_arn}"
}
```

The guide does not include a principal in its policy, so I do not understand why I am getting an error. Can anyone give me any help or advice on how to move forward with this?

Comment: This is from CloudFormation or terraform templates?

Comment: This CMK was created manually, so no template.

Comment: Your KMS policy is fine. You don't need the second statement that generates the error. Have you tried without it?

Comment: I am unable to even add the second statement, so I have only been using the first statement so far. The SQS queue receives messages successfully when the encryption is disabled. Once the encryption is enabled with this CMK, then it stops receiving messages published from the SNS topic. Is there any way you know of to further debug why that key policy is denying my encrypted SQS queue to not receive messages from my unencrypted SNS topic?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue. Your key policy (the first one provided) is enough in my tests.  You shouldn't need the "producers" policy at all.

Comment: How do you test it? I used "Publish message" option in sns topic.

Comment: I am using "Publish message" in my SNS topic as well to test. I just published a message with encryption disabled for my SQS queue and the message was received successfully. I also did the same thing but with my SQS queue having encryption enabled using my KMS CMK with the first key policy above. The message is not being received by my queue now.

Comment: Strange. I can't replicate the error. Everything that you use, sns, sqs and kms are in same region and account?

Comment: Yes, all services I am using (KMS, SNS, SQS) are in the same region and account.

Comment: Are you using envelope encryption, in which case you're missing a permission : https://lobster1234.github.io/2017/09/29/aws-kms-envelope-encryption/

Comment: So I created a new SNS topic and encrypted SQS queue and the messages send successfully. I checked the original SNS topic and SQS queue and it looks like the message has ended up in the DLQ, where it has been received hundreds of times. Some info to add is that I have a Java client listening to my SQS queue and pulling messages from it. It seems that the issue is not in publishing the message, but my Java client receiving the message. I will likely create a new question for this but if you have any initial thoughts on what the issue is based on this information please feel free to let me know.

Comment: So the issue is not the policy and my policy is correct?

Comment: The policy I already had was correct. To resolve the consumer permissions, I attached the IAM policy in the "Configure KMS permissions for consumers" section to the consumer user and everything works correctly now.